# preg_replace function: How to search a string without considering a section in it?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$string='Stack overflow in <font color="yellow"> "yellow"</font> font';
$words='"yellow"'
$string=preg_replace('/'.$words.'/i', 
                     "<font style=\"background-color:blue;\">$0</font>",
                     $string);
```

The string "yellow" is a parameter from a different function.
preg_replace finds the  "yellow" inside the font tag also. How do I avoid the font tag when using preg-replace?

#### Edit - desired output (newlines introduced for ease of reading only)

```
Stack overflow in <font backgroundcolor="yellow">
<font style="background-color:yellow">"yellow"</font></font> font
```

Comment: I don't get it - what do you want as an output? You want to replace all occurences of `"yellow"` with `<font style="background-color:yellow;>"yellow"</font>`? What do you want your `$string` to come out as?

Comment: could you show your desired output...

Comment: I want to replace all occurrences of "yellow"(yellow in double quotes) with "yellow" with background colour. But i donot want the preg_replace to search inside the html tags. Also i cannot remove the html tags from the string.

Comment: So in your example above, there should be no change, since the two occurences of `"yellow"` are either part of the `<font` tag, or contained between the `<font></font>` tags? Or did you want the output to be `Stack overflow in <font color="yellow"><font style="background-color:yellow;>"yellow"</font></font> font`?

Comment: I am sorry. Actually the $words and $string comes as argument to a function it can be anything. The eg. i took was not apt. whatever comes in as arguments the preg_replace should not look into any of the html tag parameters ie inside < and >. How to get a suitable regexp for that

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is (as a one-liner, as I think it actually helps readability in this case):

```
$string = preg_replace('/backgroundcolor="yellow"/i',
 'style="background-color:yellow;"',
 'Stack overflow in <font backgroundcolor="yellow"> "yellow"</font> font');
echo $string;
```

... this gives the output "Stack overflow in  "yellow" font"

If, instead, you mean you want to replace the other instance of "yellow", then this is what you want:

```
$string = preg_replace('/"yellow"</i',
 'style="background-color:yellow;"<',
 'Stack overflow in <font backgroundcolor="yellow"> "yellow"</font> font');
echo $string;
```

... this gives the output "Stack overflow in  background-color:yellow;" font"

Basically, you identify which one you want to change by adding just enough extra detail to match only one and not the other.

For a more general purpose solution like @mathematical.coffee's, something like this might work better (edited to reflect specified output):

```
$string = preg_replace('/>(.*)("yellow")(.*)</i',
 '$0<font style="background-color:yellow;">$1</font>$2',
 'Stack overflow in <font backgroundcolor="yellow"> "yellow"</font> font');
echo $string;
```

Comment: Actually no, 
`code` $string = preg_replace('/"yellow"/i', 'style="background-color:yellow;"', 'Stack overflow in <font backgroundcolor="yellow"> "yellow"</font> font');
`code`
But i donot want preg_replace to catch the first "yellow" inside <font> tag

Comment: It's a little confusing when you use the word "inside", because inside could either mean <font [here is INSIDE THE TAG]>[here is OUTSIDE THE TAG]</font>, or it could mean <font [here is THE TAG ITSELF]>[here is INSIDE THE TAG]</font>.  It seems that you mean the first one.  This is why it's helpful for you to give your desired result, which appears to be: Stack overflow in <font backgroundcolor="yellow"> style="background-color:yellow;"</font> font. Correct? As opposed to Stack overflow in <font style="background-color:yellow;"> "yellow"</font> font, which would be solved by my first answer?

Comment: I think its still confusing for both of us, my desired o/p in the case is Stack overflow in <font backgroundcolor="yellow"><font style="background-color:yellow">"yellow"</font></font> font. Though the html o/p is same in many cases, the $words and $string comes as argument to a function it can be anything. The eg. i took was not apt. whatever comes in as arguments the preg_replace should not look into any of the html tag parameters ie inside < and >. How to get a suitable regexp for that

Comment: finally .. ! If you specify what output you want from the get go (ie when you ask your question), you will avoid many answers that aren't quite what you want.

Comment: That i figured out now, I a newbie into this... Thanks a lot guys it is working

Comment: Ah, now that I look back at your original question that makes sense.  I've updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
preg_replace('@$words(?![^<>]*>)@i',
             '<font style="background-color:yellow;">$0</font>',
             $string);
```

The `(?![^<>]*>)` is a *negative lookahead*.

It says, "match `$words`, but **not** if it's directly followed by:

- a `>`: means the "yellow" is *within* an HTML tag. The `[^<>]*` means to stick within the current tag.

This assumes that your HTML is well formed - you don't have `<` or `>` in your text that is *not* part of a tag (i.e., assumes all stray `<` and `>` have been turned into `&lt;` and `&gt;` already).

(Updated based on the desired output).

Comment: However I think OP wants to exclude text replacement in any HTML tag not just `<font>`.

Comment: But every bit of text is eventually in some sort of HTML tag, even if it's just `<body></body>`. I need some more clarification from OP.

Comment: This is a far more general purpose method than mine, and could easily be modified to be non-tag-specific.  The issue I have is that this specific task is more likely than most to be matching against a large document with lots of matches, and (by my best understanding) a negative lookahead is going to add a lot of overhead to this replacement.